# How to calculate weighted score based on full text search for different columns and sum them in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I want to calculate a weighted score based on a full-text search for certain columns in PostgreSQL table. I have three columns in a table (table name: People) named location, interest and industry. All the columns have multiple data into them stored in an array.

This works fine with MYSQL. I want a similar query in PostgreSQL.

```
select *, (MATCH (interest) AGAINST ('javascript python')*0.6
+ MATCH (location) AGAINST ('ahmedabad')*0.3
+ MATCH (industry) AGAINST ('IT services')*0.1) as score
FROM people order by score desc
```

The query should return the score for each record based on the full-text search and the weights for each column.

`Match()` and `against()` are used for **full text search**.The string in the `against()` argument is being searched in the indexed column for matches. All the words separated by a space are considered as different substrings for full-text searching.

For the above query the expected output should be:
[image]

Comment: Can you describe what `MATCH ... AGAINST` does and how to interpret the result value? I am too lazy to look up MySQL documentation.

Comment: Postgres has very different methods for full text search:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/textsearch.html.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Match() and against() are used for full text search.The string in the against() argument is being searched in the indexed column for matches.All the words separated by a space are considered as different substrings for full text searching.

Comment: Thanks. How should one interpret the result of `MATCH ... AGAINST`?

Comment: [`ts_rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html) or maybe `setweight()` might be what you are looking for

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please explain this with an example? I have tried it but it doesn't fulfill the requirement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Question edited.